# C#: can't ReadKey if my parent is a window application and it is redirecting my stdout

Tags: c#, .net, io-redirection

I am trying to catch the output from a child console app.

- When the parent is a console app everything works.
- When the parent is a windows app then the child fails to run with an exception from `Console.ReadKey()` saying there is no way to readKey when the stdInput has been redirected.
  However, I am not redirecting the input (only the output).

What am I missing here?

Child Code (set project to console app):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChildProcess
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("stdout");
            Console.Error.WriteLine("stderr");
        }
    }
}
```

Parent app code: (set project to windows app)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RedirectProcessOutput
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"ChildPRocess.exe";
            string arg = "i";

            string processOutput = "?";

            Process p = new Process();

            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;

            p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
            p.Start();

            processOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit();

            Console.WriteLine("The child process output is:" + processOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the application to run without crashing even when the parent is a window app since the child should have its own console and I am not redirecting the input for that. 
BTW - everything works when:

- the child is not doing a "ReadKey" or
- the parent is not redirecting stdout at all

Answer (score 1):

Since it works correctly when the parent process is a console application, why not just temporarily turn it into one?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool FreeConsole();

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process p = new Process();

    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;

    p.StartInfo.FileName = "Child.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "i";

    AllocConsole();
    p.Start();
    FreeConsole();

    string processOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();

    Debug.WriteLine("The child process output is:" + processOutput);
}
```

If you use a `lock` around `AllocConsole`/`Start`/`FreeConsole`, you can even start up multiple child processes, each with its own console window.

---

This is an older 'solution' that did not work properly.

Take a look at the [CreateProcess flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863.aspx). Not setting CREATE_NO_WINDOW doesn't give you a new console object; you need CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE. [nope, this was wrong; see below]

Unfortunately, that isn't exposed in the .NET API. `Process.Start` does the right thing if you let it use `ShellExecute`, but then you can't redirect stdout. I think what you are trying to do is impossible with `System.Diagnostics.Process`, you will have to P/Invoke `CreateProcess`.

Just yesterday I wrote my own `System.Diagnostics.Process` alternative because I needed another feature not provided by the MS implementation - redirect both stdout and stderr to the same stream. Feel free to reuse [my code](https://gist.github.com/dgrunwald/5331022), but keep in mind it didn't get much testing yet.

I've tested your example with my `ProcessRunner`, and it works as expected if the parent process is a console application - the child gets its own new console window (not reusing the one from the parent as `System.Diagnostics.Process` does), it can `ReadKey()` from it, and stdout is redirected to the parent.

But if the parent process is a windows application, this breaks down -- `ReadKey()` fails; and `stderr` output also isn't visible. (this is exactly the same behavior as `System.Diagnostics.Process`, I just didn't realize that `stderr` also wasn't working. The reason for this is that you can't just redirect one of the streams - as soon as `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` is set, all the streams are redirected.

Now I'm not sure why it works if the parent application is a console. Maybe the redirected stdin/stderr handles refer to the current console, not the console that was current when `GetStdHandle` was called.

But if `GetStdHandle` is called within a Windows application, it returns INVALID_HANDLE. I'm not sure if there's a way to get a handle that will be valid once a console is created.
Answer: do don't that, just create the console earlier (see new solution at beginning).

Comment: thanks. I tried the PInvoke path, but redirecting the output looks like too much work right now (I have something similar in C++, but I am not inclined to write it again in c#). I decided to change the child process to a window application (so it can do input). It looks kind of ugly (that would be my poor UI skills), but does what I want.

Comment: @OSH: I found a simple solution by temporarily creating a console for the parent process. Oh and I somehow thought you were actually starting a child process outside of your control, so that you __had__ to use its stdout. If you can change the child process, you could also create a pipe unrelated to stdout/stderr.